# Javascript: обработчик изменения размера элемента (естественное изменение)

Tags: javascript, html

Есть div, имеющий min-width и min-height. При добавлении текста(скриптом) его размеры увеличиваются автоматически.
Как отследить его новый размер?

Я пробовал использовать

```
element.offsetHeight
```

Но получается неверный результат (больше чем надо) сразу после добавления текста. А если получить значение этого свойства через некоторое время, получается верный результат.

Возможно, после установки текста, нужно некоторое время для... правильного размещения его в диве?

```
<div class="parent"><div class="popup"></div></div>
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .parent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .popup {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  .popup:before, .popup::before, .popup:after, .popup::after {
    content:"";
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0];
  popup.innerHTML = 'любой текст от 3 до NNN строк';
  console.log(popup.offsetHeight);
</script>
```

И нет, padding тут не при чем. Разрыв между начальной неправильной высотой и правильной тем больше, чем больше текста, по сравнению с прошлым значением.

Comment: Текст добавляете скиптом? Какие события повешены на блок есть при добавлении текста?

Comment: Событий никаких.
Да, текст добавляю скриптом, а затем сразу запрашиваю новые размеры.

Comment: Напишите разметку и скрипт в вопрос а то я попробовал у себя у меня возвращается высота. просто без разметки не получится написать ответ

Comment: Добавил разметку, стили, код.

Comment: А что не правильного то, все работает как нужно возвращает 140?

Comment: У меня не удается повторить ошибку на кастомном примере.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37532/discussion-between-userx-and-user64675).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `popup.elementHeight`